# Where to do a join to flatten table..? Hive or Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have 7 normalized tables in oracle that I need to flatten out(some columns, not all) to work with map-reduce jobs. Now I have 2 choices- one is to do a join in oracle and use sqoop to import the joined table in hdfs. Or to import the tables one by one and then do join using hive itself.

Is there any difference between the two approaches, pro's or cons?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am well comfortable with both oracle and hive.  In this case seems reasonable to get the join done in oracle. You can ensure that all the moving parts are in sync and available.

You may also consider to  create an oracle  view  that embodies the join. You can then more repeatably verify and extract the contents of the various tables into your single denormalized one.